# Print rows based on criteria?

Tags: excel, printing, criteria, rows, countif

I'm a bit new to excel but so far I have gotten the hang of some of the formulas. What I did is created a countifs formula to search for certain criteria in the columns. However, what I want to do is based off of what I searched for using countifs, I want to display the rows that the countifs searched for in a separate sheet. For example, if I searched through column A and found that 3 rows in column A had the word "Hello" in them, I would want to print out the rows that have the word "Hello" in column A in them. Is there a simple or automated way to do so? I would not like to do it manually through filters. If anyone could help that would be great! Thanks!

An example of rows and columns would look like this:

```
Animal    Owner    Phrase
Cat       Jack     Hello
Dog       Jill     Bye
Elephant  Henry    Hello
```

In this case I would use countifs to look for "Hello" which would display the rows for in a separate sheet.

```
Cat       Jack     Hello
Elephant  Henry    Hello
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to do so, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The best way to start is to turn on the macro recorder and then manually do what you want the code to do. Then turn off the recorder and use the recorded code as your starting point.

Comment: It sounds like a VBA function may be the best approach. Can you post a small sample of the data (a few rows should do) and describe where you want the output to be printed relative to the columns in your data and the rows that match the search criteria?

Comment: The rows are very long. I simply looked for certain key words in the columns and my countifs tracked them. I would want to print them out with all the same column headings as I had in the original page, but I just want to "pull them out" so to speak and put them into a separate excel file with all the same column headings.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in filters in excel, and display only the rows that match a certain criteria (either the columns where you have a countif is > X, or by each column) and then print that?

"Home" ribbon, panel "Editing, Sort&Filter

Comment: I want to automate this process. I am currently writing Visual Basic Code to do this. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: A pivot table is what you are looking for then. Or an array formula with INDEX and SMALL. If you really want to it in VBA (will be slower), then just loop through each line of the table and copy that line into the new sheet below the previous line if it matches your criteria. Let me know if you need a piece of code to do so.

Comment: Oh sure, i would appreciate some code or an outline on how to do so if possible. I just want to get an idea on how to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you want to do it in VBA:

```
Sub SortByCondition()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer, r As Integer
Dim rFirst As Integer, rLast As Integer
Dim wSin As Worksheet, wSout As Worksheet ' I like to have variables when working on multiple sheets for clarity and ease of use

Set wSin = Sheets("Raw") ' The sheet where you have unsorted data
Set wSout = Sheets("Sorted") ' The sheet where you will copy the sorted data

' This is to find the first and last row in your table... there are many other ways to do it
With wSin.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion  ' Replace with first cell in your table
    rFirst = .Rows.Row + 1  ' Assumes the first line of your table is the header
    rLast = .Rows.Count + .Rows.Row - 1
End With

r = 2 ' We'll start copy on row 2 in the output sheet

For i = rFirst To rLast Step 1

    If wSin.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Hello" Then  ' I'm assuming we test for 'Hello' being in column C

        Range(wSin.Cells(i, 1), wSin.Cells(i, 3)).Copy wSout.Cells(r, 1)   ' We'll copy in columns A to C in the output sheet
        r = r + 1

    End If

Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the prompt response! I just have one more quick question. I realized a pivot table may be easier for maintainability in the long run as I would probably have to add/change rows around. I just had a quick question--I want to put dates and strings where the value filter is in a pivot table--is that possible? I noticed I can only get numbers there though